# how to show div after another div is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a survey evaluation box.

I made a div and inserted 4 headings in them. they are displayed none.

the survey has four questions and after the 4th question is answered the Evalv box is appearing.

What I am trying to do is when eval div has appeared it must show (question 1 valid...then after 1-sec question 2 valid... and so On) And then result box must appear.

Hope You are getting what I am trying to say...

Now I am able to get up to show the evaluation box but not the animation part. I am new to jquery and I not getting the any logical steps so I can follow them.

I appreciate any form of help guys. And thanks in advance for your time.

Here is the link for the page I am trying to model: http://courses.healthshul.com/test1/

After completion of 4 questions the survey evaluation part I am not able to model.

thanks again

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do it and here is a simple one, by calling `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` and inside the fade Out make the following div fade In. 
See the code snippet for more details :

```js
$('.results').hide();
$('.results.first').fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(2000,function() {
   $('.results.second').fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(2000,function() {
      $('.results.third').fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(2000,function() {
  $('.results.fourth').fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(2000,function() {

        })     
      })
   })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='results first'>Question 1 Result</div>
<div class='results second'>Question 2 Result</div>
<div class='results third'>Question 3 Result</div>
<div class='results fourth'>Question 4 Result</div>
```